# Encoding issue when running an R-script in a batch file

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

Using a batch file in Windows (.bat) I am unable to run an R-script, which contains the letter ä. The R-script (one_line.R) is only one line:

`df <- read.csv2("filename_ä.csv")`

When changing the letter "ä" to "a", it works using the batch file. Running the script in RStudio, after having re-opened the script with encoding UTF-8, it works even with the letter "ä" in the file name. Surely there must be a way of successfully running the script using the batch file too, but how?

The .bat-file is also very simple:

`"C:\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\one_line.R"`

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you import the data using `data.table::fread`.

Comment: If you *don't* store the script as UTF8, how do you expect to load such a non-ANSI character correctly? This would only work if your system locale (described as `the locale used for non-Unicode programs`) matched the non-ANSI character, eg if you saved the script with a German codepage and tried to execute it on a machine with a German locale. If you *don't* specify UTF8, R reads the script as an ASCII file using the system locale's codepage

Comment: This is no different than web applications. The only way to *avoid* mixups in non-English, is to save the page as Unicode. Even if one argues that you can use the same ASCII codepage throughout, what happens when you have to combine characters from *two* codepages? Eg, combine beer bottle sales from Germany, Poland and Ukraine?

Comment: For some reason, it works in the batch too when saving the R-script in ISO-8859-1 (System default).